# Find position equal columns of matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

Consider the following rectangular matrix

```
M = {{1,1,1,1},{2,2,4,4},{3,3,5,5},{9,9,3,1}}
```

I would like to extract the position of equal columns. Is there a simple function or algorithm working with any matrix? By acting with a function (or using an algorithm) on `M`, I should get `{1,2}` as output.

More generally, there may be two sets of equal columns, as in the following case

```
 M = {{1,1,1,1},{2,2,4,4},{3,3,5,5},{9,9,3,3}}
```

in which case the output should be `{{1,2},{3,4}}`.

Is there something already implemented in `Mathematica`? I need a clever and fast algorithm which can be applied to big matrices of size `200x200`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `GatherBy` and `Select`:

```
M = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 4, 4}, {3, 3, 5, 5}, {9, 9, 3, 1}};

Select[GatherBy[Range[Length@M[[1]]], Transpose[M][[#]] &], Length[#] > 1 &]
```

> {{1, 2}}

Also

```
 Select[Length @ # > 1&] @ Values @ PositionIndex[Transpose[M]]
```

> {{1, 2}}

```
M2 = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 4, 4}, {3, 3, 5, 5}, {9, 9, 3, 3}};

Select[GatherBy[Range[Length@M2[[1]]], Transpose[M2][[#]] &], Length[#] > 1 &]
```

> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}

```
 Select[Length @ # > 1&] @ Values @ PositionIndex[Transpose[M2]]
```

> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}

Comment: Umh.. this does not work well. For example, the matrix posted here https://pastebin.com/BJZ6VmKe has the columns 14,17,24 equal.I think you should modify the command as `Select[GatherBy[Range[Length@Transpose@M], 
  Transpose[M][[#]] &], Length[#] > 1 &]`, right?

Comment: @apt45, thank you. Fixed it.

Comment: Thank to you ;) !

Comment: Hi again! Is there any way to speed up the algorithm when dealing with ~60000 columns and ~60 rows? Thanks!

Comment: `Values@PositionIndex[Transpose[M]] `is much more performant! I would suggest to add this to the answer. Cheers.

Comment: @apt45, it is not surprising that removing the additional layer of processing (`Select[Length @ # > 1&]`) from the last approach will make it much faster if it is ok have the positions of non-duplicates (singletons in `Values@PositionIndex[Transpose[M]]`)  in the output.

Answer (score 1):

Using `SequencePosition` (new in 10.1)

```
a = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 4, 4}, {3, 3, 5, 5}, {9, 9, 3, 1}};

SequencePosition[Transpose @ a, {x_, x_}]
```

{{1, 2}}

```
b = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 4, 4}, {3, 3, 5, 5}, {9, 9, 3, 3}};

SequencePosition[Transpose @ b, {x_, x_}]
```

{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}

Answer (score 1):

```
M1 = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 4, 4}, {3, 3, 5, 5}, {9, 9, 3, 1}};

M2 = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 4, 4}, {3, 3, 5, 5}, {9, 9, 3, 3}};
```

Using `SequenceCases` and `Position`:

```
elems = SequenceCases[#, s : {x_ , x_} :> Splice@s] &;

Union@Map[Position[Thread@M1, #] &, elems@Thread@M1]
```

> {{{1}, {2}}}

```
Union@Map[Position[Thread@M2, #] &, elems@Thread@M2]
```

> {{{1}, {2}}, {{3}, {4}}}